# How to disable pop up app manager? It's driving me crazy

Tags: banner

Here is a screenshot

[image]

I have no idea how to disable this menu from popping up. I have no idea what it's even called. It pops up frequently and it is ruining my life.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to > `System Setting` > and then `Keyboard` > then click `Shortcuts` and inside keyboard shortcuts click `Navigation` then down the list a little bit is `Switch Application` click on the `ALT + F2` and hit `BACKSPACE`. That will clear the shortcut for application switcher and it should not longer bother you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is still doing it though. I'm using a MBpro with a touchpad and the popup menu just randomly appears. And by random I legitimately mean it appears random. I cannot recreate it, but I think if through some combination of my fingers/shirt/whatever, the menu is triggered through the touchpad.

Comment: I done a little bit of research and found out that there is multi touch gestures on touchpads for ubuntu. I found a wiki here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch , I will do some more research to see If I can find a solution to disabling this App Switch Gesture for you.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you press **Alt** + **Tab**. If you don't press them, then it won't show up anymore.